# Minimum coin change or 0-1 knapsack

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, coin-change

I have data set like this:

Length: 233, 333, 450, 560, 650, 780
Limit: 5400

Now my problem is to choose item from length set highest to lowest to make up the limit or come as close as possible.

I know both knapsack and minimum coin change can solve my problem. I would like to know which one would be preferable.

Note that coin change is uses greedy algorithm and knapsack uses dynamic programming

Comment: If two algorithms are appropriate, always the one is the better one which you manage to implement in shorter time. If you spend too much effort on deciding you are wasting valuable company time. If this is not a helpful answer for you it means that you have an actual attribute you want to optimise, maybe speed, maybe code size, maybe RAM need. It would be helpful to explain your optimisation goal. Otherwise this question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: A really interesting optimisation goal is to impress teachers or interviewers. In that case have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016753/how-to-impress-interviewers-with-my-coding-what-practices-can-i-adopt-in-the-c/57016940#57016940

Comment: My goal hear is to optimize computing time and implementation. I would like to use coin change with greedy approach as it is very easy to implement. But would I get the optimized set of length that make up the limit each time for any data set?

Comment: So you actually doubt that both algorithms are appropriate? I think you should [edit] your question to phrase more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of your question, it seems that you're debating whether your problem can be solved with a greedy algorithm or if it is more like the 0-1 knapsack problem, and a greedy algorithm would not give you the optimal solution every time.

**Here is some background information about greedy algorithms and the 0-1 knapsack problem:**

To expand on greedy algorithms, they work on the basis that there is some universally optimal property to choose the next item from, and work locally. In other words, for an algorithm to be greedy, it must have the **greedy choice property and optimal substructure**, meaning that the first choice made by the greedy algorithm *can* be chosen in an optimal solution, and that an optimal solution contains the optimal solution to smaller subproblems within it.

The 0-1 knapsack problem, on the other hand, is *not* a problem that can be solved greedily. This is most obviously observed in the fact that the greedy choice property is *not* displayed. There is not a single attribute to pick your first and next items based of off; if you choose the largest item, it may be that it happens to take up too much space and there are no smaller items that can fill that space, whereas choosing smaller items would have completely filled the knapsack. If you choose smaller items first, it may result that your knapsack now has a space that is too small for larger items to fill, and choosing one of those larger items earlier would have completed the knapsack.

0-1 knapsack is a problem that requires a **dynamic programming** solution, which operates non-locally and in layman's terms, is a form of optimized "brute-force". In other words, it can be thought of as an optimization over recursion.

---

**Your problem is to choose discrete items to fulfill or come as close to the maximum length limit.**

This sounds like to me, almost exactly like the 0-1 knapsack problem, which cannot be solved with a greedy algorithm if you want the optimal solution with any dataset.

Instead, we want to use dynamic programming, and you can tell that a problem can be solved this way if it has both **optimal substructure** and **overlapping subproblems**.

The 0-1 knapsack problem displays **optimal substructure** due to:
The maximum value that can be obtained from a data set of n items and W weight is either: the maximum value from n - 1 items and W weight, OR, the maximum value from n - 1 items and W - weight of item n, plus the value of n.
Each of these subproblem's optimal solutions can be combined to create the optimal solution for the larger problem.

The 0-1 knapsack problem also has **overlapping subproblems** due to:
The recursive solution to the problem involves trying all combinations of n items and checking whether the weight of those items are less than W, then finding the maximum of those values. This inherently involves a lot of repetitive work, such each combination of items tried can be calculating the same total as previously calculated on fewer items, and therefore, using simple combinatorics, you can see that the time complexity becomes factorial.

That is why the 0-1 knapsack problem and your problem would be best solved using dynamic programming, so you can save answers to previous subproblems and refer back on your already-calculated sums to solve later problems that depend on the overlapping subproblems' answers.

-

Thank you, and good luck!